# VoIP socket для ios приложения

Tags: ios

Есть приложение которое работает в фоновом режиме, создал сокет через [либу](https://github.com/ndcube/WebSocket-for-Objective-C) там четко даю ему понять что он должен работать в фоне, Все должно бы быть нормально, но после 1 минут работы в фоне сокет убивается :(

Кто сталкивался, что можно сделать что бы сокет не закрывался и продолжал работать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Единственную линку которую нашел можно поглядеть [тут](http://wiseman-safiq.blogspot.ru/2010/11/ios-executing-code-in-background.html)